# SpatialLines to iGraph conversion simplifies topology

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to convert from spatialLinesDataFrame to igraph object, and think I may be losing information I want to keep. Fairly new to igraph so please bear with me.  The example below illustrates:

```
# create sldf object
require(sp); require(igraph); require(shp2graph)
d = data.frame(x = c(0,80,100,0,-20,-8,0,3,-10,-5,80,75),
               y = c(0,-10,5,0,14,33,0,-4,-10,-12,-10,5),
               grp = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4))

sl = SpatialLines(list(
  Lines(list(Line(d[d$grp == 1,1:2]),
             Line(d[d$grp == 4,1:2])), ID=1),
  Lines(Line(d[d$grp == 2,1:2]), ID=2),
  Lines(Line(d[d$grp == 3,1:2]), ID=3))
)

sldf = SpatialLinesDataFrame(sl, iris[1:3,])
plot(sldf)
```

[image]

Now convert to igraph and plot:

```
read_sldf = readshpnw(sldf, ELComputed = T)
g = nel2igraph(read_sldf[[2]], read_sldf[[3]], weight=read_sldf[[4]])
plot(g)
```

[image]

Am I right that the off-branch of the first spdf row (`sldf[1,]`) has been lost?  Calling `as_edgelist(g)` returns 3 rows not 4.

Comment: Yes, exactly. `sl2 = SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(d[d$grp == 1,1:2]), ID=1), Lines(Line(d[d$grp == 2,1:2]), ID=2), Lines(Line(d[d$grp == 3,1:2]), ID=3))); sldf2 = SpatialLinesDataFrame(sl2, iris[1:3,]); read_sldf2 = readshpnw(sldf2, ELComputed = T)`. I made the object from the `SpatialLines` not having 1st `Lines`'s 2nd `Line`.  `identical(read_sldf, read_sldf2);   [1] TRUE`. `readshpnw()` clarly read only 1st `Line` par `Lines`. If give `Detailed=T`, `readshpnw()` doesn't read 2nd `Line`.

Comment: Thanks @cuttlefish44 that explains. I guess it's not possible to capture the physical network (maintaining full topology) and duplicating the attribute where necessary?  `readshpnw(sldf, Detailed = T)` returns `Error in readshpnw(sldf, Detailed = T) :   If a detailed graph is to be built, the properties of its attributes has to be specified`

Comment: As far as I can see, `Detailed = T` doesn't work without `ea.prop`. `read_sldf_d = readshpnw(sldf, ELComputed = T, Detailed = T, ea.prop = rep(0, 5))` seems to have at least all coordinates information about each 1st `Line`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change those options in readshpnw:

```
# create sldf object
require(sp); require(igraph); require(shp2graph)
d = data.frame(x = c(0,80,100,0,-20,-8,0,3,-10,-5,80,75),
               y = c(0,-10,5,0,14,33,0,-4,-10,-12,-10,5),
               grp = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4))

sl = SpatialLines(list(
    Lines(list(Line(d[d$grp == 1,1:2]),
               Line(d[d$grp == 4,1:2])), ID=1),
    Lines(Line(d[d$grp == 2,1:2]), ID=2),
    Lines(Line(d[d$grp == 3,1:2]), ID=3))
)

sldf = SpatialLinesDataFrame(sl, iris[1:3,])
plot(sldf)

nodes = readshpnw(sldf, ELComputed = TRUE, Detailed = TRUE, ea.prop = names(sldf))
g = nel2igraph(nodes[[2]], nodes[[3]])
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks reasonable. I can't even remember what this project was about now!